# Give SFTP users and Apache write permissions on same folders

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions, centos6, file-permissions, sftp

I have a centos6 web server where developers also upload by connecting through SFTP. So, to give developer login write permissions, I have change /var/www user to that user. My current permissions are:
developer:root
and with these, SFTP developer login can upload files, but apache can't upload files in them even with 777 permissions. I even tried with setting permissions like developer:apache, but of no avail.

How would I give both Apache and SFTP login write permissions at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would recommend you to use acls here:

```
setfacl -R -m user:apache:rwx directory
setfacl -R -d -m user:apache:rwx directory
setfacl -R -m user:developer:rwx directory
setfacl -R -d -m user:developer:rwx directory
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way around else using ACLs?

Comment: you can use common group for apache and developer, and then use sgid on directory (chmod -R g+s) to assure, that newly created files are with the same group.

Comment: But I wonder that what made a user do negative marking on my question. :O Was it a bad question? I did a lot of search really before posting my question.

Comment: I don't know :-) Maybe it was too trivial?

Comment: there's another issue now. Apache is fine and scripts can upload and change text dynamically. but sFTP developer user can not overwrite existing files owned by root. In WinSCP, they give timestamp issue. Is there any way around for this?

Comment: @Hashmi I think the timestamp message in WinSCP is just a warning. The files still get updated.