# sFTP users permissions to overwrite/edit over root owned files

Tags: filesystems, centos6, sftp, access-control-list

This is related to [Give SFTP users and Apache write permissions on same folders](https://serverfault.com/questions/665188/give-sftp-users-and-apache-write-permissions-on-same-folders) So, I am using ACLs to give write permissions over `/var/www`. It works perfectly when developer login users upload new files inside `/var/www` but problem happens when they try to overwrite files owned by root. I have a script which creates folders and files under `/var/www`, so permissions are automatically set to `root:root`, so to enable developer login to overwrite/edit existing files, I have to run `chown developer:root`every time. So, I need a way that developer login can overwrite files owned by `root:root`. Please suggest me solutions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script that creates the directories/files, add the 'chown developer' at the end to make the newly created files owned by the correct user.  This seems much preferable to having root-owned files writeable by non-root users.

However, I don't quite understand why ACLs aren't doing the right thing; if you have set the 'default' ACL, that should ensure newly created directories/files within should inherit the ACLs.  The only thing I can think of there is that when using ACLs the "group" permission bits become a 'mask', so if you want a 'write' ACL to apply, the directory/file needs to have the group write bit set.